# Images not appearing in document

Tags: graphics, errors, pdf, sharelatex, tocstyle

I'm using the online tool shareLatex and trying to compile a document that has many images. The images do not appear.

However, I created another test file and pasted the same preamble of the original document and the code related to the images; it compiles and the images appear.

How can I find the problem?
No errors are thrown upon compilation.
Thanks for any help.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[nopostdot,  style=super, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfgantt} 
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


%------------------------------------------------------
%Table

    \usepackage{enumitem, etoolbox, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother


%------------------------------------------------------



%\newcommand{\autodot}{.}

%----------------------------------------------------
%Add some level of subclasses
\newenvironment{subs}{\adjustwidth{2em}{0pt}}{\endadjustwidth}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]

\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\theparagraph.\arabic{subparagraph}}

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{subsection}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}



%-----------------------------------------------------
%Space Before and After Sections and Subsections Titles 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}

%------------------------------------------------------
%Space Between Lines
\linespread{1.15}

%-------------------------------------------------------
%Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber ,bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=numeric, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Rename the contents title
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Content}

   %Add dot after the section number



\overfullrule=0pt
\hypersetup{final}



%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------Begin The Document------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{Video_based}
        %\caption [An Example of Video-Based CAPTCHA]{An Example of Video-Based CAPTCHA Presented in \cite{kluever2009balancing}.}
        %\label{fig:Video_based}
    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you still using draft mode as in your previous question? This would disable the images.

Comment: @samcarter Is this mode enabled by default? I'm using the online editor and I'm not sure if these setting is something default. How can I disable it, and if I did is it will affect the rest of the document?

Comment: Usually its somewhere in the preamble, for example `\documentclass[draft]{book}`

Comment: @samcarter No unfortunately I don't have such thing in the code. Is it possible to share the document with you to see you may notify with the cause of the problem, since I couldn't copy it and paste it here

Comment: could you please add a MWE? Maybe the preamble, some content, and a dummy figure to work with, so to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I updated the question with the test file that worked with me but the original one didn't worked, actually this is what make me very confused?  like the same preamble and the same image code but I don't have the output images in the original document:(

Comment: you can check my answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce the issue you are having, I went ahead and pasted your code in Sharelatex.

It seems the tocstyle packages is in alpha version and is causing the problem.
Here is the warning:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocstyle.sty

Package tocstyle Warning: THIS IS AN ALPHA VERSION! USAGE OF THIS VERSION IS ON YOUR OWN RISK! EVERYTHING MAY HAPPEN! EVERYTHING MAY CHANGE IN FUTURE! THERE IS NO SUPPORT, IF YOU USE THIS PACKAGE! Maybe it would be better, not to load this package.
```

Solution is to comment lines 24 and 26:

```
%\usepackage{tocstyle}
%\usetocstyle{standard}
```

Funny thing is that if I re-enable the lines, the figure is compiling no problem after the initial compilation with the commented lines. I guess kudos for finding a bug.

Here is the [proof](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/djcyrqpnnmhr) to the solution.

Comment: But how can I comment it while I need it inside the code :(. And both codes have the same package but one produce the image and the other is not.

Comment: try compiling without first then un-comment lines and compile again. Sorry I cannot help you more than that, the sole maintainer of this package is https://ctan.org/author/kohm

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, thank you so much for your help brother I appreciate it. At anytime if you want me to share the project with you I don't mined it. Thank you so much

Comment: Brother finally it has worked with me, I created a new file and copied my code with comminting the package ang the images appeared. Thank you so much